# Error in category_id[[x]] : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r

I want to add a JSON file to my dataframe called Video5
the code :

```
    data <-rjson:: fromJSON (file='CA_category_id.json')

category_id <- list()
d <- jsonlite::fromJSON('CA_category_id.json')
for (i in 1:nrow(d$items)){
  category_id[[d$items[i,]$id]] <- d$items[i,]$snippet$title
}
vedio5[, 'category'] <- sapply(vedio5$category_id, function(x) category_id[[x]])
vedio5[, 'category'] <- sapply(vedio5$category_id, function(x) category_id[[x]])
for (i in 1:length(vedio5)){
  vedio5[[i]][, 'category'] <- sapply(vedio5[[i]]$category_id, function(x) category_id[[x]])
}
```

This code does not work and I get a message:Error in category_id[[x]] : subscript out of bounds

note:Each of the JSON file contains id ranging from 1 to 44 (both inclusive). And with each id is given its category and other information related to title, kind etc. Hence, we can use any one of the JSON files to map category to category id in our data frame

Comment: Is the `for` loop intended to loop over the rows? I believe `length(vedio5)` is the number of columns.  You can try `nrow` instead.